# How do I test my date formatting function?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, localization

I have a function that formats dates, and a unit test for that function.

It uses `new CultureInfo("en-US", useUserOverride: false).DateTimeFormat.MonthDayPattern` to format date strings.

```
var dt = new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year, 1, 1, 12, 30, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var actual = The_Function_Under_Test(dt);
var expected = "January 01";
```

Recently, a change to the `"en-US"` culture data has caused this test to fail:

```
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual); //Expected: <January 01>, Actual: <January 1>
```

What is a good way to reliably test the output of this function, without having to update it every time the `CultureInfo` changes?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like your question contradicts what you're trying to do. You have a function that verifies a certain culture is formatted in a specific way. If that culture format changes, your test should fail, by definition.

That of course begs the question, as to why are you unit testing non-critical code you don't own. There's nothing inherently wrong with it, if your code depends on a fragile 3rd party assembly, but this output is just used to dump data to screen, is it not?

If you're hard-coding en-US in your function already, you might as well disregard the culture and output your own hard-coded format, which will never change. If you're internationalizing your application, and support multiple cultures, I'd leave that test out, since the proper way to implement a test would be to invoke the culture and dump the formatted date, which is literally what your helper function does.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. The function under test prints user-friendly date strings like "just now", "a minute ago", "3 hours ago", "today at 3:30pm". This particular test is for what happens when the DateTime is January 1 of this year. (It should output `dt.ToString(__.MonthDayPattern)` in that case.)

Comment: I think you're right that I shouldn't be testing the culture format at all. `var expected = dt.ToString(MonthDayPattern)` in this case, `var expected="3 hours ago"` elsewhere.

Comment: I agree. All your test should care about is whether you get a specific user friendly sentence out of a date, which is abstracted above a culture. Whether or not you're using a specific culture is a private implementation detail of your helper. You obviously have a choice to use a less fragile solution by hard-coding, and you're not relying on culture to display the data anyway.